# In an Eclipse Java project that is dependent upon two other projects, how do you resolve jar conflicts?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

This is the situation as best I can describe (I didn't create this project, so I can't say why it was done this way).

I have 3 projects:

SupportProject_A

SupportProject_B

MainProject which is dependent upon both support projects (in required projects in the build path).

SupportProject_A has SomeJar1.0.jar

SupportProject_B has SomeJar2.0.jar

The name spaces and class names are the same in both version of SomeJar, but the class definitions differ.  This is causing havoc because eclipse is complaining that SomeClass.method does not exist, which it does in SomeJar2.0.jar, but not in the 1.0 version.

Is there a way, in MainProject to say, ignore SomeJar1.0.jar from SupportProject_A?

Comment: If you have project X depend on project Y, you can choose which jars of project Y to export to project X. There you can only select the JARs you want project specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse used to build projects? It's so 2001.

But, anyway. There is two options:

1) Use one version of the library for every project.

2) Use maven.

My choice would be to use maven as relying on IDE to build your project is a bad practice.

Comment: For #2, Gradle is another option to evaluate.

Comment: I am not using eclipse to build my project.  The actual thing that caused this to rear its ugly head is that I was asked to introduce unit tests.  So I install the the required libs and other setup, but when I run it as a junit project, the whole JUNIT thing pukes (some sub-system not directly related to JUNIT) I am getting these class conflicts between the Jars... Anyway, the Maven thing is on the table.  It is on another Developer's To Do list.  ETA, unknown.  I was seeing if i could get this working before then.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency management system like Maven or Gradle (Gradle is my fav though). You get the plugin for both in eclipse. Once you figure out which one suits your requirement, find out which jar version is suitable for both the projects and add that to the build.gradle file along with the repository that has these versions. You should be able to setup the whole project with gradle and gradle takes care of the rest!! Good luck.